# Transpose date into local timezone without shifting the date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an input date with a specific time zone in string. For example:

`Sat May 20 2017 17:00:00 GMT-0300 (-03)`

I want to change the timezone of this date to my local timezone without converting the time. As if the input date was in my correct timezone.

`Sat May 20 2017 17:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`

I played around with moment and found this:

`const date = moment(moment.utc('Sat May 20 2017 17:00:00 GMT-0300 (-03)').format('LLL'))`

Is it the simplest way to do it? I don't like the copy of the moment object but I can't find a method to do it in a "single shot".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To parse your input in local time, you can simply use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) function. As [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) says:

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.

Here a live sample:

```js
var input = 'Sat May 20 2017 17:00:00 GMT-0300 (-03)';
var m = moment(input, 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss');
console.log(m.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. The key here was to specify the input format to remove the timezone parsing. Never thought about that.